# U1DB problems with apparmor

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, apparmor

I'm having problem with u1db and apparmor. The application works fine, but when it is packaged apparmor does not allow the app to save data into $HOME/.local/share/.. so I can't actually save my settings between different executions. This is what I can read into my log...

```
kern.log:Jan  5 23:45:38 swordfish-XPS12 kernel: [10599.303619] type=1400 audit(1388961938.954:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=8115 profile="com.ubuntu.developer.flscogna.ubuntu-netwalk_ubuntu-netwalk_0.9" name="/home/swordfish/.local/share/ubuntu-netwalk/ubuntu-netwalk-settings.db" pid=13381 comm="ubuntu-netwalk" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

The apparmor json file is this:

```
{
"policy_groups": ["networking"],
"policy_version": 1
}
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
"description": "Ubuntu NetWalk app",
"framework": "ubuntu-sdk-13.10",
"hooks": {
"ubuntu-netwalk": {
"apparmor": "ubuntu-netwalk.json",
"desktop": "ubuntu-netwalk.desktop"
}
},
"maintainer": "Filippo Scognamiglio <flscogna@gmail.com>",
"name": "com.ubuntu.developer.flscogna.ubuntu-netwalk",
"title": "Ubuntu Netwalk",
"version": "0.9"
}
```

And the U1DB inside the application:

```
U1db.Database {
    id: settingsDatabase
    path: "ubuntu-netwalk-settings.db"
}

U1db.Document {
    database: settingsDatabase
    docId: "settings"
    create: true
    defaults:{"glowing": "true",
              "difficulty" : "INSANE",
              "roration" : "false"}

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var tempContents = {};
        tempContents = contents;
        glowing = Boolean(tempContents["glowing"]);
        difficulty = tempContents["difficulty"];
        rotation = Boolean(tempContents["rotation"]);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tempContents));
    }

    Component.onDestruction: {
        var tempContents = {};
        tempContents["glowing"] = String(glowing);
        tempContents["difficulty"] = String(difficulty);
        tempContents["rotation"] = String(rotation);
        contents = tempContents;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tempContents));
    }
}
```

If someone has any idea why this is not working it would be really really appreciated... thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your application name is set in the program to be "com.ubuntu.developer.flscogna.ubuntu-netwalk", as it is in the manifest file.  In a QML app, set the `applicationName` attribute of the `MainView` to this value.  In a C++ application, call

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("com.ubuntu.developer.flscogna.ubuntu-netwalk");
```

When it's running, the program uses this value to figure out which directory is writable, but apparmor uses the value in the manifest file to decide where to allow file system access.  If these aren't the same, you run into problems.  (Why the program can't get its application name directly from the manifest file, I don't know.)

Comment: Yes! You definitely get it right!... I thought the name in the manifest was enough, but I was wrong... Thank you very very much. You made my day!